# How do I randomly pick ANY character (Letters+ Symbols + Numbers)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am really new to Python (5 Days). I decided that I wanted to see if I could make a password generator. After around 5 minutes I came up with this code.

```
import random
import string

length = int(input("Enter the desired length of password: "))
values =string.ascii_letters
for i in range(length):
    letter = random.choice(values)
    print(letter, end="")
```

This basically asks the user how long they want their password to be and generates a random password of that length. However, the string.ascii_letters *thing* only allows me to randomize alphabetical letters (a-z)(A-Z). Is there any *beginner friendly* way in which I can make it choose between all characters like numbers and symbols too. Your advices would be really helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just add them to the values:

```
values = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
```

Comment: Absolute Legend. Didn't know those existed too. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

```
import string
string.printable
```

Would give you all the printable strings

```
>>> string.printable
'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~ \t\n\r\x0b\x0c'
```